# How to get Google user ID from OAuth's token response for Latitude service?

Tags: google-oauth

I'm trying to setup a service so a Google user authorizes my platform then I can get his/her Latitude data anytime.

Currently I get the GoogleTokenResponse so I get the access and refresh tokens. However, I need to identify that response so if several users want to enable the service somehow concurrently I can match the token response to the corresponding user.

How should I achieve this? I've tried parsing the id token but I get a null exception:

```
GoogleIdToken gidt = tokenResponse.parseIdToken();
```

(The tokenResponse is not null; as said before I can get the tokens with no issue). However, the API javadoc says it would return an obfuscated user id, so it wouldn't probably suffice.

Answer (score 0):

There are details missing in this question and a lot of paths through this code. If you are getting an ID Token you can parse it and discover which user it belongs to, see things like http://javadoc.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/1.8.0-beta/com/google/api/client/googleapis/auth/oauth2/GoogleIdToken.html#verify(com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleIdTokenVerifier)